# How to implement/setup BPMN2 diagram with two successive exclusive gateways

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I  have a BPMN2 diagram with two successive exclusive gateways. In my first gateway, I have two expression condition types for the yes and no lines:

```
${enoughDrinks}
${notenoughDrinks}
```

Following this exclusive gateway, I have a second exclusive gateway with the same yes and no lines and an additional third line "other option". My problem is: how do I have to set this up? When I run the process and get to the no line of the "Enough drinks" gateway, I get an error for the boolean expression condition of the second gateway:

```
 Unknown property used in expression: ${otherOption}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'otherOption'
```

I have declared the variable in the execute method of my class that implements the JavaDelegate class:

```
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
  boolean otherOption = (Boolean)execution.getVariable("otherOption");
  execution.setVariable("otherOption", otherOption);
}
```

Below is the BPMN diagram and the red arrow points to the problematic line.

[image]

Maybe the general question is: if it is even possible to have to successive exclusive gateways without a user task inbetween?

Comment: Please post your process definition. When do you execute your JavaDelegate? There is no ServiceTask in the process. Do you have an Execution or TaskEventListener ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not seem to have any service tasks defined the in your process: where is the delegate executed?

Try to add it as a "start" listener to the 2nd gateway